# How to let lines in MusixTex & MTX auto-breaking?

Tags: music, musixtex, page

I'm a very beginning user of MusixTex. I try to test some codes as follows:

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{article}
\usepackage{musixdoc}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}\nostartrule
\parindent10mm
\instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
\setname1{Piano} % whose name is Piano
\setstaffs1{2} % with two staffs
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}% 4/4 meter chosen
\startextract % starting real score
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{dgf}|\qlp i\en
\notes\tbu0\qb0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{dgf}|\qlp i\en
\notes\tbu0\qb0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\ql l\sk\ql n\en
\bar
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{dgf}|\qlp i\en
\notes\tbu0\qb0g|\ibbl1j3\qb1j\tbl1\qb1k\en
\Notes\ibu0f0\qb0{cge}\tbu0\qb0g|\hl j\en
\zendextract % terminate excerpt
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]
There's only one line, the line did not auto-break. 
This is just an example. No matter how many notes I input in the original text, there's only a line in the result.

And I tried MTX to input as follows:

`Title: Edelweiss
Composer: Richard Rodgers
Style: piano
Sharps: 1
Meter:3/4
%% Ac4
e2 g4  | d2d+       | c2 g4   | f2d       | e2  e4  | e4 f4 g4  | a2d    | g2d    |
c4 g2+ | b4- g4+ g4 | a4- e2+ | a4- c4 f4 | g4- e2+ | g4- a4 b4 | a4 f2+ | g4 f2+ |`

The result is:
[image]
again only 1 line, no auto-breaking.

So how to let the line auto-break and fit the A4 paper ?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

`\startextract`...`\zendextract` is used for pieces shorter than one line, so it doesn't support line-breaking. Use `\startpiece` and `\endpiece` instead, and you should be good.

In addition: after the first compile, you may notice some extra white space on the right of each of the lines. Now if you look in your folder, you should see a newly generated `.mx1` file. Run `musixfls foo.mx1` (if `foo.mx1` is the filename that you see), and then compile your `.tex` file again, to fully resolve the line widths and hence eliminate the extra space at the end.

Comment: For me to resolve extra white spaces after using `\startpiece` and `\endpiece` I have to run `musixflx foo.mx1` instead of `musixfls`. Otherwise the procedure was same as in *imnothere*'s answer and works fine for me.